# Andras the Black Dog

Tags: divinity-original-sin-2

He summons a necrotic troll that one-shots almost any individual party. He also gets initiative.

Other than waiting until I have a level advantage how I can deal with this goon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few options I could recommend but unless you provide some more information about your party and levels I can't give you every idea.

1. Get your level high enough, if you are under leveled, most fights are difficult. It is usually easier to level up elsewhere and come back. It is also important to make sure your gear is also up to date. You may be an appropriate level, but if you have under leveled gear you won't stand much chance against higher level enemies.
2. Take your tankiest character and have them initiate the fight, you can either talk to the dog with pet pal or straight up attack him to initiate the fight. While you do this, have every other character in your party be in sneak away from the area, out of sight entirely and broken in chain from the one starting the fight.

   2a. You will want to use each other character one at a time, and move them into the fight, attacking the dog from sneak mode for a free move. All the while don't be advancing the fight with the one who initiated it. Your goal here is to take out the dog first. Summons will automatically die if you kill the one who summoned it.
3. If you have the shackles of pain skill, have the one with that skill initiate the fight with them and cast it onto the dog after his armor is removed. How you go about this is up to you. (You could use the sneak tactic again to remove armor).

Comment: Was hoping to do it without cheese-tactics or pure luck.  Suggestion 2. worked.

Comment: I don't think that method is entirely too cheesy, glad it worked out though. I will see if I can help you with your more recent question now.

Answer (score 0):

I beat him mainly with 2 heavy melee characters. I enraged them both, then had Beast Fury him, and Ifan All In him. That hit him for like 600 damage. At that point, you can start using Physical status effects.

I also found it useful to Charm the Undead Archers as they appear. As soon as the first Undead Archer was summoned, I got rid of its magic armour using Searing Daggers + Spontaneous Combustion and then charmed it. It supplies about 160 physical damage per turn which is pretty useful.

I also teleported the Golem away when it was getting close to one of my guys. That buys you a turn at least.